# No template update after createRecord with findQuery fetching

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm wonder why my template doesn't get updated after `createRecord` when using `findQuery` to fetch data.

When changing this `return this.store.findQuery('timetracking', {year: year, month: month, user_id: user_id});` to `return this.store.find('timetracking');` the template gets updated with my new records.

I don't want to fetch all records to save bandwith, but when using only `find/findQuery` with query params, my newly created records doesn't show up in my template.

Do I have to do a "force" reload? And how to do this?

**Update**

The Ember inspector shows the new records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findQuery` puts the job of filtering on the server's back.  Ember Data assumes that the results that were returned are the only results that are associated with that collection.  `find` with no query or id (`findAll`) will always return all records found in the store, because it realizes you weren't looking for any filtered set, if you create a new record it gladly knows to include it in all of the available records.  You can manually push a record into a collection of records using `pushObject`.

```
// assuming you're in the context of your `findQuery` results, and they are the model
var model = this.get('model'),
    record = this.store.createRecord('timetracking', {...});

model.pushObject(record);
```

Comment: For anyone having issues with pushing the object directly to the model, push the object's _internalModel.

`this.get('model').pushObject(record._internalModel);` This was the solution to my problem